# convert dataframe column into textfile (iterating rows to line)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I´ve got something like this in a pandas dataframe:

```
Name,Total,Problem
Toyota,2,'They don’t need the oil consumed per trip, only a sum of manually counted damage.'
Mazda,1,'Hello, I got an engine error. See attachment below.'
Kia,2,'Client requires a confirmation that the information provided through CODEXXXX asap.'
Volkswagon,3,'During visual inspection of lights we have found a damage.'
```

And I´m interested in getting the `df['Problem']` column and convert it to a textfile, so the textfile outputs is as follow:

```
They don’t need the oil consumed per trip, only a sum of manually counted damage.
Hello, I got an engine error. See attachment below.
Client requires a confirmation that the information provided through CODEXXXX asap.
During visual inspection of lights we have found a damage.
```

I don´t even need an index in the text file, because it´ll be used in a text tagging application (and has to enter in that format). Even if the row/element in the `df['Problem']` is a paragraph long string, it has to be in a single line in the textline.

Comment: Does `df['Problem'].to_csv(filename, index = False)` work?

Comment: @HS-nebula: the csv formatter would quote the lines containing the separator which is not desirable here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
with open('sample.txt','w') as f:
    for data in list(df['Problem']):
        f.write(data+'\n')
```

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The `tolist()` method of a Series can do most of the job here. You can either build the whole text in memory (if the df in not too big) with `join`:

```
with open(file, 'w') as out:
    print('\n'.join(df['Problem'].tolist()), file=out)
```

Or print it element by element if you want to save memory:

```
with open(file, 'w') as out:
    for line in df['Problem'].tolist():
        print(line, file=out)
```